# Sort collection using BeanComparator and Collator

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort a List of nodes using this code:

```
private String sortPropertyName;
private void sortListUsingSortorder(List<MyNode> nodes, String sortOrder) {
        BeanComparator comparator = new BeanComparator(sortPropertyName, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
            if ("dsc".equals(sortOrder)) {
                return ((Comparable) obj2).compareTo(obj1);
            } else {
                return ((Comparable) obj1).compareTo(obj2);
            }
            }
        });

    Collections.sort(nodes, comparator);
    }
}
```

I want to use a Collator to achieve following sortorder:

AaÄäBbCcUuÜü

something like this

```
    Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
    Collections.sort(words, collator);
```

How can I use this Collator in my sorting code?

Comment: But your comparator doesn't sort Strings. How is a Collator relevant?

Comment: there will be an if statement in my new method to check if obj1 and obj2 are instances of String and then use the Collator.

Answer (score 1):

Delegate to the collator in your comparator:

```
BeanComparator comparator = new BeanComparator(sortPropertyName, new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        if ("dsc".equals(sortOrder)) {
            return collator.compare(obj2, obj1);
        } 
        else {
            return collator.compare(obj1, obj2);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's a problem with the collator. Not a problem with your comparator. Use SECONDARY instead of PRIMARY for the letter without trema to be before the corresponding letter with trema.